# Find two pairs where neither is the case ⟨x1,y1⟩⪯⟨x2,y2⟩, ⟨x1,y1⟩⪰⟨x2,y2⟩.

Tags: order-theory

can you help me find any two pairs where neither ⟨x1,y1⟩⪯⟨x2,y2⟩,  ⟨x1,y1⟩⪰⟨x2,y2⟩. Neither should be the case.

Comment: (1,2) and (2,1)

Comment: How are you defining $\preceq$ here?

Comment: ⪯ is defined by relationship ⟨1, 1⟩ ⪯ ⟨2, 2⟩, if 1 ≤ 2 ∧ 1 ≥ 2

Comment: can the pairs commented by Jean Marie be used for my definition?

Comment: In what set do $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$ reside, Jack?

Comment: And what do you mean by $⟨x1,y1⟩⪰⟨x2,y2⟩.$

Comment: Jack, this is a duplicate question of your earlier question.  DO NOT REPOST questions, for whatever reason ("I didn't get an adequate answer" nor "My question got closed", nor for any other reason).

Answer (score 0):

$⟨1, 1⟩ ⪯ ⟨2, 2⟩,  \iff  1 ≤ 2 ∧ 1 ≥ 2$

Imagining the graph of this:

So we write $\vec{A} ⪯ \vec{B}$ when either $\vec{A}$ appears to the left(or not to the right of) of $\vec{B}$ AND when $\vec{A}$ appears above (or not below) $\vec{B}$.

So then consider $\vec{A}=(0,0)$ and $\vec{B}=(1,1)$.

$\vec{A} ⪯ \vec{B}$ is false because $0=y_1 <y_2=1$

$\vec{B} ⪯ \vec{A}$ is false because $1=x_1 > x_2=0$

$\vec{A}$ is not above $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{B}$ is not to the left of $\vec{A}$.

Comment: so ⟨1, 0⟩ ⪯ ⟨0, 1⟩ and ⟨0, 1⟩ ⪯ ⟨1, 0⟩?

Comment: Wait what? Those aren't the points I give. I may be reading this wrong but do $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ fit the bill?

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand. Can you give me any two pairs?

Comment: @Jack+ anyone: Do $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ fit the criterion of the problem? Because you should be able to find more if it meets your needs but I am worried I am misreading this problem.

Comment: Well, my answer would be  ⟨1, 2⟩ ⪯ ⟨2, 1⟩ and ⟨2, 1⟩ ⪰ ⟨1, 2⟩ but afaik ⟨1, 2⟩ ⪯ ⟨2, 1⟩ is true, right? I need both to be false, if I understand this correctly.

Comment: Right. Ok I am with you. But what about the points I am suggesting? 

Is it the case that $⟨0, 0⟩ ⪯ ⟨1, 1⟩$ and $⟨1, 1⟩ ⪰ ⟨0, 0⟩$ both evaluate to false?

Comment: Tbh I am lost. I can't provide compatible two pairs.

Answer (score 0):

We need to negate

$$((x_1 \leq x_2) \wedge (y_1 \geq y_2)) \vee  ((x_2 \leq x_1) \wedge (y_2 \geq y_1))$$

which is just the combination of the two relations $(x_1,y_1) \preceq (x_2,y_2)$ and vice-versa.

By DeMorgan, this is equivalent to:
$$ \neg ((x_1 \leq x_2) \wedge (y_1 \geq y_2)) \wedge \neg ((x_2 \leq x_1) \wedge (y_2 \geq y_1)) $$

$$ \equiv((x_1 > x_2) \vee (y_1 < y_2)) \wedge ((x_2 < x_1) \vee (y_2 < y_1)) $$

$(2,1)$ and $(1,0)$ satisfy the above, since $x_1 > x_2$ and $y_2 < y_1$. You can confirm that they also satisfy the original statement.

Answer (score -1):

Choose
$x1 < y1$ and
$x2 > y2$.

(1,2) and (2,1) 
as Jean Marie commented.

Comment: so ⟨1, 2⟩ ⪯ ⟨2, 1⟩ and ⟨2, 1⟩ ⪰ ⟨1, 2⟩? afaik the first one is right (therefore can't be used)

Comment: One of us is reading this problem wrong... and it could be me.

Comment: No : the point is that you have neither (a) (1,2)⪯(2,1) nor (b) (2,1)⪯(1,2). Let us explain (a) for example : one should have $1 \leq 2$ AND $2 \leq 1$ ; but the second inequality is false...

Comment: $⟨1, 2⟩ ⪯ ⟨2, 1⟩$ because $1=x_1 \le x_2=2$ and $2=y_1 \ge y_2=1$

Comment: but this is true, right?

Comment: marty  How can you even begin to answer when you don't event know the set in which $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ reside?  Pretty careless answer, seems to me.

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. I spell my name "Danger".

Comment: Marty Danger Cohen: I actually think it's a totally reasonable to guess that the set we were discussing was either $\mathbb{R}^2$ or even $\mathbb{N}^2$. I mean... it's very likely that this is what is being discussed (and if it isn't then I would argue it's on the OP to be more specific) but I downvoted because your answer is incorrect. Which I pointed out after the OP pointed out... Mason NotThatDangerousButKindaDangerousButNotReally...

Comment: It's an annoying name to spell... takes forever to sign checks...